# No sound devices detected and partially no sound card detected on new fedora 31 install

Tags: fedora, drivers, audio

Yesterday i shredded my fedora 30 install, since it kept dying on me due to some issue with nvidia drivers breaking when updating. I then installed fedora 31 workstation and all was well until i wanted something to listen to. Turns out fedora does not detected any input or output devices, no matter if usb or through the audio jack, I tested it with multiple devices. I did not have this issue on my fedora 30 install, so the hardware should be working (with linux).

Some online research leads me to believe that my sound card is not being detected or is missing some "modules"/drivers.

Running the following commands yields this:

```
> aplay -l
aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...
```

```
> lspci -nnk | grep -i -A7 audio
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio [8086:a2f0]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:1220]
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:a2a3]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Other
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:a2a3]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 HDMI Audio Controller [10de:10ef] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:3752]
04:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller [1b21:0612] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Motherboard [1849:0612]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
05:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM2142 USB 3.1 Host Controller [1b21:2142]
    Subsystem: ASRock Incorporation Device [1849:2142]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

```
> lsmod | grep snd
# nothing
```

```
> dmesg | grep -iC 3 audio       
[    0.392803] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.392803] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.392803] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.392803] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.392803] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
[    0.419989] ACPI: 9 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.424314] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
```

```
> dmesg | grep -iC 3 snd
# again nothing
```

```
> alsa-info.sh                                                               
ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64
--------------------------------

This script visits the following commands/files to collect diagnostic
information about your ALSA installation and sound related hardware.

  dmesg
  lspci
  aplay
  amixer
  alsactl
  /proc/asound/
  /sys/class/sound/
  ~/.asoundrc (etc.)

See '/usr/sbin/alsa-info.sh --help' for command line options.

cat: /proc/asound/version: No such file or directory
cat: /proc/asound/cards: No such file or directory
cat: /proc/asound/modules: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/dev/snd/*': No such file or directory
alsactl: save_state:1595: No soundcards found...
cat: /tmp/alsa-info.5zdMQV29oh/alsactl.tmp: No such file or directory
```

EDIT: output of `alsa-info.sh --no-upload`

```
upload=true&script=true&cardinfo=
!!################################
!!ALSA Information Script v 0.4.64
!!################################

!!Script ran on: Sat Apr  4 10:55:14 UTC 2020


!!Linux Distribution
!!------------------

Fedora release 31 (Thirty One) NAME=Fedora ID=fedora PRETTY_NAME="Fedora 31 (Workstation Edition)" LOGO=fedora-logo-icon CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:fedoraproject:fedora:31" HOME_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/" DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/f31/system-administrators-guide/" SUPPORT_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Communicating_and_getting_help" BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/" REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Fedora" REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=31 REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Fedora" REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION=31 PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Legal:PrivacyPolicy" Fedora release 31 (Thirty One) Fedora release 31 (Thirty One)


!!DMI Information
!!---------------

Manufacturer:      To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Product Name:      To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Product Version:   To Be Filled By O.E.M.
Firmware Version:  P3.20
Board Vendor:      ASRock
Board Name:        Z370 Extreme4


!!ACPI Device Status Information
!!---------------

/sys/bus/acpi/devices/ACPI000C:00/status     15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT33A1:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/INT3F0D:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0103:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0501:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:02/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:04/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C02:06/status      3
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C04:00/status      31
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0C:00/status      15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0E:00/status      11
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:00/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:01/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:02/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:03/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:04/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:05/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:06/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/PNP0C0F:07/status      9
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:7f/status   15
/sys/bus/acpi/devices/device:8e/status   11


!!Kernel Information
!!------------------

Kernel release:    5.5.13-200.fc31.x86_64
Operating System:  GNU/Linux
Architecture:      x86_64
Processor:         x86_64
SMP Enabled:       Yes


!!ALSA Version
!!------------

Driver version:     
Library version:    
Utilities version:  1.2.2


!!Loaded ALSA modules
!!-------------------



!!Sound Servers on this system
!!----------------------------

Pulseaudio:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/pulseaudio)
      Running - Yes

Jack:
      Installed - Yes (/usr/bin/jackd)
      Running - No


!!Soundcards recognised by ALSA
!!-----------------------------



!!PCI Soundcards installed in the system
!!--------------------------------------

00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio [8086:a2f0]
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 HDMI Audio Controller [10de:10ef] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device [1458:3752]


!!Loaded sound module options
!!---------------------------


!!ALSA Device nodes
!!-----------------



!!ALSA configuration files
!!------------------------

!!System wide config file (/etc/asound.conf)

#
# Place your global alsa-lib configuration here...
#


!!Aplay/Arecord output
!!--------------------

APLAY

aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

ARECORD

arecord: device_list:274: no soundcards found...

!!Amixer output
!!-------------


!!Alsactl output
!!--------------

--startcollapse--
--endcollapse--


!!All Loaded Modules
!!------------------

acpi_pad
bridge
coretemp
crc32_pclmul
crc32c_intel
crct10dif_pclmul
drm
drm_kms_helper
e1000e
ebtable_broute
ebtable_filter
ebtable_nat
ebtables
fat
fuse
ghash_clmulni_intel
i2c_i801
iTCO_vendor_support
iTCO_wdt
ie31200_edac
intel_cstate
intel_powerclamp
intel_rapl_common
intel_rapl_msr
intel_rapl_perf
intel_uncore
ip6_tables
ip6t_REJECT
ip6t_rpfilter
ip6table_filter
ip6table_mangle
ip6table_nat
ip6table_raw
ip6table_security
ip_set
ip_tables
ipmi_devintf
ipmi_msghandler
ipt_REJECT
iptable_filter
iptable_mangle
iptable_nat
iptable_raw
iptable_security
irqbypass
joydev
kvm
kvm_intel
libcrc32c
llc
mei
mei_hdcp
mei_me
nf_conntrack
nf_conntrack_broadcast
nf_conntrack_netbios_ns
nf_conntrack_tftp
nf_defrag_ipv4
nf_defrag_ipv6
nf_nat
nf_nat_tftp
nf_reject_ipv4
nf_reject_ipv6
nfnetlink
nvidia
nvidia_drm
nvidia_modeset
nvidia_uvm
nvme
nvme_core
stp
sunrpc
tun
vfat
video
x86_pkg_temp_thermal
xt_CHECKSUM
xt_CT
xt_MASQUERADE
xt_conntrack


!!ALSA/HDA dmesg
!!--------------

[    0.392719] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.392719] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.392719] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
```

I am rocking an asrock z370 extreme4 with no external sound card, so the onboard soundcard found by lspci should be the correct one. Kernel version is `5.5.13-200`.

Has this happened to anyone of you people ? This issue is really annoying me, since I can't really do home office if i cant talk to my colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

Since i found no real solutions to this problem, I deleted my fedora install and reinstalled it again. Now the audio works with any problems or additional tinkering, so i guess something just went wrong with the previous install.